# How to use "no sooner... than..."?

Tags: vocabulary

The structure "...no sooner...than..." is reported to be used only 
in past tense, yet I wonder whether it is OK to use it to describe a daily habit.
For example:

> Every day, as soon as I return home, I turn on the computer to post some messages.

Is it Ok to say:

> I have no sooner returned home every day than I turn on the computer to post some messages.

Or the structure can only be used in past tense.

Please explain in detail, thanks very much!

Comment: Are you saying _I have returned home_ is present?

Comment: @Edwin: well... it is.

Comment: And it isn't: '**perfect tense** - a tense of verbs used in describing action that _has been completed_ (sometimes regarded as perfective aspect)' (no mention of 'present') // 'The present perfect is a grammatical combination of the present tense and the perfect aspect, used to express **a past event** that has present consequences.'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect] (so the action is completed, past, no matter what we call the structure).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is at best suitable for ell.


Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, no sooner works best in past tense

> No sooner had I returned home than I turned on the computer

In today's English, I would use *As soon as* if I need present tense

> Every day, as soon as I return home, I turn on the computer to post some messages.

If you MUST, then the construct would be

> No sooner do I return home from school than I turn on the computer

but it sounds stilted to my ears

Comment: No sooner will I flee from the grasp of evil than would I fight the presence of your corporation in my community.

Comment: Any now give me an example from this millennium ;) Please see update

Comment: What's wrong with 'No sooner do I return home each night, than the telephone rings' ?

Comment: It sort of matches my last example which I wrote after the comment. I updated with yours

Comment: It certainly can be used in the generic present (like all of the examples), because a generic verb represents something that happens generally, and therefore has happened in the past. [Generic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/generictoafault.pdf) is present tense but not present time. It's what happens to non-stative verbs when they are used in the present tense, like the verb phrase _are used_ in the previous clause.